# How can I use (run) MigLayout in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, ide, jar, eclipse-indigo, miglayout

I'm using eclipse Indigo and I'm making GUI, I've decided to use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) cause swing layouts really sucks and they are unhelpful a and have confusing code. 
 
Back to the point, I've
downloaded  [this .jar](http://java.net/projects/miglayoutfx2/downloads) from MigLayout pages. But I've did't find how to "use" it = add in my environment. 
It will be probably easy thing, but now it's quite serious problem for me, cause I've never did it before and doesn't any clue how to start.
**So my question is how should I make it work in eclipse?** (download this, put it there and set this .. first steps.)

**Edit (Solution according answer):** 
The best way is download **miglayout-4.0-swing.jar** there: [link](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/versions/4.0/) 
Also helpful is reading **file.txt** which explain what are the files useful for. 
And in miglayout-4.0-sources.jar are source files of some demos for MigLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the build path of your projects. 
Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs/Add external JARs depending on where you keep the lib.

Btw are you sure you need the fx lib?

Comment: U're right I downloaded another 2 jars. But this is exactly what I needed. Thx